# Safari causes our Active Directory accounts to be locked?

Tags: safari, active-directory

I work for a giant corporation who, as typical with giant corporations, has rather lackluster desktop IT support.

We run Windows XP on our machines. Our small dev group requires that we have Safari to do some local testing on our machines. After jumping through hoops to get it installed, it works just fine.

However, there's one giant drawback and that's if we leave Safari open on our machine, we eventually get a small network pop-up asking us to login to one of our corporate servers. If we ignore this, our Active Directory account is eventually locked.

This has happened consistently enough with a few of us that we're fairly confident that that is the connection: leaving Safari open locks our Active Directory account.

Of course, I can't think of a possible connection or where to even start debugging this. Since our tier one support teams read a script stating that they don't support Safari, we don't get very far with them so I am hoping to find a bit more information before hunting down a higher level support group.

Any theories?

Comment: There may be a proxy login that's being requested by Safari. Only thing I can think of.

Comment: Yea, that's my theory too. If that is the case, who would be the group to bug...the Active Directory Networking group?

Comment: Difficult one to ask. Why is it seemingly random? Perhaps Safari is phoning home.